# c# socket Thread

Tags: c#, node.js, multithreading, sockets

Trying to thread the socket through c# winform. I don't know if this code is working properly. If not, I want to dispose of the sockets with threads. Ask for help.

There is a message that the client and server are connected, but they do not receive data from each other. I have no idea what the problem is.

```
private void Login_box_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string email = textBox1.Text;
            string pw = textBox2.Text;

            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate ()
            {
                this.Invoke(new Action(() => socketLogin(email, pw)));
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }));

            thread.Start();
}
```

```
private void socketLogin(string email, string pw)
            {
                var loginjson = new JObject();

                loginjson.Add("email", email);
                loginjson.Add("password", pw);


                var socket = IO.Socket("http://localhost:3000/login.html");
                socket.On(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, (data) =>
                {
                    socket.Emit("socketlogin", loginjson.ToString());  
                });

                socket.On("login", (data) => {  
                    MessageBox.Show(data.ToString());

                });

            }
```

server  node.js

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('connection');
    socket.on('socketlogin', function(data) {  

        var testLogin = { 'Login': "success" };

        socket.emit('login', data);
    });
  });
```

Comment: 1) Spawning an explicit thread that simply thread-marshals (via `Invoke`xxx) back to the UI serves no purpose 2) If you must invoke use `BeginInvoke` since `Invoke` can lead to application dead-lock 3) `Sleep`ing at the end of a thread serves no purpose.  Consider using `async/await` equivalents

Comment: Thank you. But I don't know how to change it. Can I ask for a little more help?

Comment: @jaebeom33 - Await Tasks, young padawan.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like the following:

```cs
private void Login_box_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string email = textBox1.Text;
    string pw = textBox2.Text;

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(socketLogin, new Tuple<string, string>(email, pw));
}

private void socketLogin(object obj)
{
    string email = ((Tuple<string, string>)obj).Item1;
    string pw = ((Tuple<string, string>)obj).Item2;

    var loginjson = new JObject();

    loginjson.Add("email", email);
    loginjson.Add("password", pw);


    var socket = IO.Socket("http://localhost:3000/login.html");
    socket.On(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, (data) =>
    {
        socket.Emit("socketlogin", loginjson.ToString());  
    });

    socket.On("login", (data) => {  
        MessageBox.Show(data.ToString());

    });

}
```

Hope this helps!